# Finding the orthocentre of a trinagle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, complex-numbers

Now, I know this has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478069/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-orthocentre) but my question is something else so please bear with me.

---

**Question:-** If the vertices of a triangle are represented by $z_1, z_2, z_3$ respectively then show that the orthocentre of the $\triangle ABC$ is

$$\dfrac{(a \sec A)z_1+(b \sec B)z_2+(c \sec C)z_3}{a \sec A+b \sec B +c \sec C }$$ $$OR$$ $$\dfrac{z_1\tan A+z_2\tan B+z_3\tan C}{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C}$$

---

**Attempt at a solution:-** 
[image: construction of triangle for orthocentre]

Now, from simple trigonometry, to be more specific, from projection law, we can see that

$$\frac{BL}{LC}=\dfrac{c\cos B}{b\cos C}=\dfrac{c\sec C}{b \sec B}$$

So we get from the section formula the coordinates of $L$ as follows

$$L \equiv \left(\dfrac{b\sec B\cdot z_2+c\sec C\cdot z_3}{b\sec B+c\sec C}\right)$$

Now, I don't know much about properties of triangles and found out the following method in a book for finding the ratio in which $H$ divides $AL$

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{AH}{HL}
&=\dfrac{ar(\triangle ABH)}{ar(\triangle HBL)} \\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}AB.BH\sin{\alpha}}{\dfrac{1}{2}BL.BH \sin{\beta}} \\
&=\dfrac{c \cos A}{c\cos B\cos C}=\dfrac{a \cos A}{a\cos B\cos C} \\
&=\dfrac{b\cos C +c\cos B}{a\sec A}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos B\cos C} \\
&=\dfrac{b \sec B+c\sec C}{a\sec A}  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$

Now I don't understand what was used in the derivation of the required ratio above, is it similarity of triangles but i don't think the triangles are similar.

**P.S.:-** Corrected the link to the question mentioned at the top.

Comment: The link in the first sentence does not seem to work.

Comment: @mathlove, sorry for the late reply. Just corrected it.

Comment: So, is your question about how to get $AH/HL=(b\sec B+c\sec C)/(a\sec A)$?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i wanted and came upon this proof which relates the area of a triangle to its sides which i didn't get how the book did it, so if you could suggest me how it was done or maybe suggest a better method or just tell me what the answer in the top link did. But, my first priority would be to understand how the book did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\dfrac{AH}{HL}=\dfrac{ar(\triangle ABH)}{ar(\triangle HBL)}$$

Because the two triangles have the common height $BL$.

> $$\dfrac{ar(\triangle ABH)}{ar(\triangle HBL)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}AB.BH\sin{\alpha}}{\dfrac{1}{2}BL.BH \sin{\beta}}$$

$$\dfrac{ar(\triangle ABH)}{ar(\triangle HBL)}=\dfrac{\dfrac 12 AB\cdot NH}{\dfrac 12BL\cdot HL}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}AB\cdot BH\sin{\alpha}}{\dfrac{1}{2}BL\cdot BH \sin{\beta}}$$

> $$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}AB.BH\sin{\alpha}}{\dfrac{1}{2}BL.BH \sin{\beta}}=\dfrac{c \cos A}{c\cos B\cos C}$$

See $\triangle{ABM}$ and $\triangle{BMC}$ :
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}AB.BH\sin{\alpha}}{\dfrac{1}{2}BL.BH \sin{\beta}}=\frac{AB\sin\alpha}{\color{red}{BL}\sin\beta}=\frac{c\sin(90^\circ-A)}{\color{red}{c\cos B}\sin(90^\circ-C)}=\frac{c\cos A}{c\cos B\cos C}$$

> $$\dfrac{c \cos A}{c\cos B\cos C}=\dfrac{a \cos A}{a\cos B\cos C}$$

Because $\frac cc=\frac aa=1$.

> $$\dfrac{a \cos A}{a\cos B\cos C}=\dfrac{b\cos C +c\cos B}{a\sec A}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos B\cos C}$$

$$\dfrac{a \cos A}{a\cos B\cos C}=\dfrac{\color{red}{a}}{a\sec A}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\cos B\cos C}=\dfrac{\color{red}{CL+BL}}{a\sec A}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\cos B\cos C}$$
Now $CL=b\cos C$ and $BL=c\cos B$.

> $$\dfrac{b\cos C +c\cos B}{a\sec A}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos B\cos C}=\dfrac{b \sec B+c\sec C}{a\sec A}$$

$$\dfrac{b\cos C +c\cos B}{a\sec A}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos B\cos C}=\frac{\frac{b\cos C}{\cos B\cos C}+\frac{c\cos B}{\cos B\cos C}}{a\sec A}=\dfrac{b \sec B+c\sec C}{a\sec A}$$

Comment: What the...!!! I just refreshed the page and there was the answer in front of me, I cannot be more thankful to you, you just get what i want to ask even if I am not much clear to state my query. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user350331: You are welcome:)